# Ignoring file sublime-text.lis as it has an invalid filename extension

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

When I try to install any program by terminal on Ubuntu 14.04 it fails with the same set of errors.

Here's what happens when I try to install sublime-text:

[image: screen from error on installation]

Comment: Your apt list is messed up! Post the output of `grep -Hn "" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` into your original post.

Comment: I had the same issue when using wifi and connection is slow (as mentioned on the screenshot). After trying again, there is no errors. I think it's connection issue. Just look at the last couple of lines.

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to make it look nice.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is

```
Ignoring file 'sublime-text.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

The filenane should end with `.list`. You can correct this by renaming the file (assuming its contents are correct):

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.lis /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

Or by deleting it:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.lis
```

You can then try to install sublime-text again with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Comment: Don't bother with `cp` then `rm` - just use `mv`. Also you can shorten the command using Bash brace expansion: `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.lis{,t}`

Comment: After fixing the extension, I think you'll need to run `sudo apt update`.